# How can I create my own GameTime for timing things in my game?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I have a `Game` class and a `GameComponent` class. I want to perform operations inside the `GameComponent` class which depend on calling `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds`, but I've noticed that that value is always 0.

At the moment I am initializing `gameTime` inside the `GameComponent` class by doing `new GameTime();`

I had the thought that somehow I should take the `gameTime` variable of my `Game` class, but I was not able to find a way to do so. I had always used `Update(Gametime gameTime)` and `Draw(Gametime gameTime)` methods in the past, which automatically gave me a game time object.

Now, that I need to deal directly with `gameTime` to run my own timing information, I see that it is a little tricky because I don't understand how it works properly. How can I create a timer for my own use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GameTime` is not a timer. It's an object representing timing information sampled at one particular point in time (from something that *is* a timer).

If you need a timer, consider using [the `Stopwatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Using a `Stopwatch` is very straightforward:

```
var timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();

... do things, read the value of timer.Elapsed or whatever...

timer.Stop();
```

`Stopwatch` also support resetting the elapsed time, pausing, and so on. The `Elapsed` property returns a `TimeSpan` which you can use to initialize a `GameTime` object if you really want.

Comment: Thank you, Josh. I have seen some weird behavior using Stopwatch. It appears not to stop counting elapsed time while in debug mode. Is this normal and/or there is a solution?

Comment: Yes, it's normal; the timer measures real-world time. You should sample the elapsed time at the start of your frame and use that same sampled value through the entire frame. You can also forcibly clamp the elapsed time to some reasonable value when debugging, or simply manually adjust the elapsed time measurement within the debugger's watch window.

Comment: Ok Josh let me ask you one last thing, please. What's the best way to sample the elapsed time at the start of a frame? in other words, when timer should be restarted? frames occur every `Draw` call? or every `Update` call? or it is something else? I thought in restarting the timer at the end of `Update` call. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Often you may want two timers; one for game logic and one for rendering. You don't need to restart the timers (but you can), you could just store the previous time and compute the delta that way. You should do it at the top of your frame so everything below can use it.